MS Access How to produce a query that returns the same as countifs
enter image description here
I have a table of customers and products.
I would like to use MS ACCESS to produce a table with a single row for each customer and a column that counts each product they buy. I can do this in Excel with Countifs but I'm unable to get the query working in MS Access.



Customer
Products




55555
Apple


55555
Pear


12345
Pear


12345
Grape


12345
Grape


22222
Grape


44444
Apple


44444
Apple


44444
Apple


44444
Apple


54544
Pear


54544
Apple



Required Access Table



Customer
Apples
Pears
Grapes




12345
0
1
2


22222
0
0
1


44444
4
0
0


54544
1
1
0


55555
1
1
0



The "group by" count query worked if I just wanted to count Apples but as soon as I added more counts the table result was empty

The output should be produced by a CROSSTAB (pivot) query. Use Access query designer to build.
TRANSFORM Count(Products) AS CountOfProducts
SELECT Customer
FROM tblName
GROUP BY Customer
PIVOT Products;

